# Javascript code(except alert()) not working in jsp file but works under .html.

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I am facing a strange problem while using javascript in jsp file. Only alert() is being executed and nothing else like Document.getElementById() works...

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" %>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home</title>


    <script language="javascript">
    function fun()
    {

    Document.getElementByID("test").innerHTML="Hello";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>

<p id="test">  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </p>
<button onclick="return fun()">Work</button>
</body>
</html>
```

But

```
function fun()
    {

    alert("Hello");
    }
```

works.

I am working with Spring MVC. Using Tomcat 8.5 server.

There are similiar questions but they are unsolved and I cannot find a solution.

Thank You

Comment: `Javsascript` is **case-sensitive** `Document.getElementByID("test")` should be `document.getElementById("test")`

Comment: Change     `Document.getElementByID("test").innerHTML="Hello";`
 to `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Hello";` since JS is case-sensitive lang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive

the script should be like

```
<script language="javascript">
    function fun() {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Hello"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was so careless.